# Not check a checkbox on condition

Tags: jquery

This solution is currently working as intented but is there a "prettier" way to do this? :)

```
if (EditCheckLog()) {
    var chk = $(this).prop('checked');
    chk = !chk;
    $(this).prop('checked', chk);
    return;
}
```

Comment: Yes, `this.checked =! this.checked`. But this question is suittable for stackoverflow, it should be on [CodeReview](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Aha did not know about CodeReview. Thanks!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this belongs to Code review

Comment: @Huangism Was searching the close reason... don't understand why *"other stack network"* doesn't have code review....

Comment: @Karl-AndréGagnon strange indeed, perhaps this should be brought up in Meta

Comment: @Karl-AndréGagnon There is a meta post about that: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/276017/add-code-review-to-belongs-on-another-site-now-that-the-site-has-graduated . It is related to how many incorrect suggestions we get for Code Review, see http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/253975/be-careful-when-recommending-code-review-to-askers

Comment: @SimonAndréForsberg Yes, I've already seen that post. I also found this one when searching : http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/266749/migration-of-code-questions-from-stackoverflow-to-codereview. Basically, code review is still in beta so it can't be a migration option.

Comment: @Karl-AndréGagnon I doubt it will be one even after. Only time will tell. However, Code Review has *technically* graduated, only waiting among many other sites for design and stuff...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to use jQuery. Here is a simple approach:

```
if (EditCheckLog()) {
    this.checked = !this.checked;
    return;
}
```